# Responsive list inside a modal (React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

the CSS has been really hard on me lately. So I am trying to make a modal that would have a scrollable list inside of it however the issue is that when I decrease the height of the browser window some of the list items are hidden from the view, also the button beneath the list is invisible and it should stay there no matter the position of the list. Can you help out, please and if possible explain what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/modal-cn73zf?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq2cy91p00062v6njzmtf0qe%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq2cy91o00022v6nm5qymbzg%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq2cy91o00032v6n2w9eotx4%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq2cy91p00052v6nk3v96b1s%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B46.13820846203578%252C53.86179153796422%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq2cy91o00022v6nm5qymbzg%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq2cy91o00022v6nm5qymbzg%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq2dx4zd00022v6nriijayyh%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A9%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A17%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A9%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A17%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FModal.css%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq2dx4zd00022v6nriijayyh%2522%257D%252C%2522clq2cy91p00052v6nk3v96b1s%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq2cy91p00042v6nrv162hkf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq2cy91p00052v6nk3v96b1s%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq2cy91p00042v6nrv162hkf%2522%257D%252C%2522clq2cy91o00032v6n2w9eotx4%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq2cy91o00032v6n2w9eotx4%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want modal content to be scrollable change to

```
.modal-content {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

and remove overflow-y: auto; from social-list

.social-list {
    max-height: 380px;
}

then add class to the form and give it 


{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[image: finally it will look like this]

[new codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/modal-forked-hvnrv6?file=%2Fsrc%2FModal.css)

Comment: That is indeed a nice approach but the button has to stay visible at all times (when we scroll the list)

Comment: updated sandbox, in app.js drag  

<button className="add-link-btn">+ Add Social Link</button>

from the form to before the modal-footer div.
This is the easiest, just because enter click here should trigger confirm button more than "add source link" you can not include it inside the form